# Wordpress: How to split Widget title like Post and title

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Hi i am working on wordpress . I want to split my Widget's Title like i did in Post-title(Given below).

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php
                global $post;

                $str = $post->post_title;
                $exp = explode(" ",$str);

                echo "<h2>".$exp[0];
                echo " <span> ".$exp[1].' '.$exp[2].' '.$exp[3].' '.$exp[4].' '.$exp[5].' '.$exp[6]."</span></h2>";?></a>


Output is:
<h1>This<span> is a title</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will might help you.

```
global $post;
 $arr = explode(' ',$post->post_title);
  $j=0;
  $str = '';
  for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){
        $j = $j + 1;        
        if($j == 1){
            $str .= $arr[$i].' <span>';
        } else{
            $str .= ' '.$arr[$i];
        }       
  }
  $str .= '</span>';
  echo $str;
```

Comment: This is the expected answer.

Comment: But where to edit or place this Solution exactly . Because i didn't found the Title in widget or Sidebar, which i want to split as i did in Post Title.